# Why my Intel 256GB SSD disk is being detected as 32kB?

Tags: hard-disk, ssd

I have 256GB Intel SSD 2500 Pro series disk. It worked great on Linux Ubuntu.
Now it stopped to work. Now it is detected as follows:

```
[69214.467957] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SandForc e{200026BB}           PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[69214.468294] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[69214.468486] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 64 512-byte logical blocks: (32.8 kB/32.0 KiB)
[69214.468746] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[69214.468748] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
[69214.469020] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[69214.469026] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through                                                                   
[69214.537252] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

Is it a disk or firmware failure ? Should I try to update the disk firmware ?

**Update 1:**
I tried to update firmware by using Intel Firmware Update Tool but the tool does not recognize the disk (in this state) as an Intel SSD.

Comment: I had a similar issue years back with a samsung drive. I sent it in to samsung for repair and flashing firmware is what they listed as the fix. Could be worth a try.

Comment: Answered here I thinkl...

https://superuser.com/questions/1604044/how-to-recover-corrupted-ssd-firmware-from-linux

Comment: @Bib my drive is being recognized exactly as `SandForce{200026BB}` . Thanks I will try the procedure